# VS2017 How to create an Empty Web "Application"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I cannot find a way to create an Empty **Web application** in **VS2017**(ASP.NET WebForm).

In VS2015 there was a template for this.

Seems like VS2017 can only create Empty Web Site.

This is what I have :
[image]

==============================================

Update for the whoever see this post in future: I Ended up rebooting my computer AND VS2017 did some updates. After that, The Empty Template appeared! Clearly a VS 2017 bug.

Comment: If you think this question is not complete instead of downvoting please give me more info. In our company, we are not allowed to choose the option of "ASP.NET Web Form Site". We have to create the web application from the scratch.

Comment: You've cropped the left hand side of the dialogue so I can't see what you've selected, but this dialogue is what I see when I select "Web Site" _under_ the "Web" option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7uoY.png

Comment: Just change your theme to light mode and you will able to see the magic.... I don't know but something should be simple in development mode but Visual studio designers are from art school (may be) they creating a cumbersome environment. A huge thing like Marvels Thanos (waiting for end game..) Try it for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to File > New Project

[image]

This will prompt you to the following Dialog where you choose for a Web App.

Then you will get to the point where you can choose a template

[image]

Comment: Is this VS2017? no idea why your interface is different from mine.

Comment: See the snapshot of interface I get in my app.

Comment: @SNash once you select "empty web application", this is a _subsequent_ dialog.

Comment: @ stuartd I do not see "empty web application" Option! please see the snapshot I put in my question.

Comment: Click on empty web site, it will get to this dialog. Otherwise try add new project instead of add new website in the menu.

Comment: @TanguyB That is exactly the steps i have been doing.

Comment: @SNash you sure you didn't click "new website" and clicked "new project", check 2nd edit of what you get when clicking "new project"